# Characteristic of a non unital integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, rngs

> Theorem: the characteristic of a non unital integral domain must be $0$ or a prime.

Assume that $mn$ is the characteristic of a the integral domain
for every $a$ in the integral domain we have $(mn)a^2=(ma)(na)=0$ then $ma$ or $na$ must be zero.

So for every $a$ in the integral domain $na$ OR $ma$ is zero but I can't say one of $m$ and $n$ works for every $a$ !

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077466

Comment: @Watson thanks a lot